# how can i append my meta data title ? in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

Currently this is the way my title is added:

```
Html.AddTitleParts( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MetaTitle) ? Model.Name : Model.MetaTitle  );
```

And this renders like this eg:

```
<title> BE Lukx.Ru</title>
```

I would like to append this ith some text and it should look like this:

```
<title>очки BURBERRY купить в интернет магазине Lukx.Ru</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NopCommerce Methode `Html.AppendTitleParts()` to append a string. If you need customized logic generating your title I would inherit or extend `Nop.Web.Framework.UI.PageHeadBuilder`. This class is marked as `partial` and every method is virtual. So it should be no problem to change the behavior of generating the page title.

Comment: i tried this way ..  Html.AppendTitleParts(" купить в интернет магазине"); 
    Html.AddTitleParts(Model.MetaTitle);
    Html.AddTitleParts(Model.Name);         but what ever i do i get the title in the wrong part like this .. <title>Lukx.Ru. очки. Adensco. купить в интернет магазине</title>
    the word Lukx.ru which is the title must come last...but the title never comes as last word no matter how ever i place the code

Comment: Which setting did you choose for "PageTitleSeoAdjustment"?